# Sitemaps: rel="alternate" hreflang="x" naming

Tags: robots.txt, xml-sitemap, multilingual, geolocation, internationalization

I'm creating a Sitemap for rel="alternate" hreflang="x", but no where in [Google's guidelines](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/2620865?hl=en) do they mention how it should be named. Also can we reference it separately in the robots.txt file, or does it need to be in a sitemap_index file?

e.g

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /private/

Sitemap: http://www.example/sitemap.xml
Sitemap: http://www.example/rel=sitemap.xml
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The naming (which is also the location) of a sitemap is - contrary to what you state in your question - mentioned in the guidelines:

- *See [Sitemap file location](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#location)*

Also the guidlines clearly say that you can specify more than one sitemap file in `robots.txt`:

> You can specify more than one Sitemap file per robots.txt file.
>
> ```
> Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap-host1.xml
>
> Sitemap: http://www.example.com/sitemap-host2.xml
> ```

- *Excerpt from [Specifying the Sitemap location in your robots.txt file](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#submit_robots)*

BTW [Sitemap index files](http://www.sitemaps.org/protocol.html#index) are used in case your file grows larger (in terms of entry count, e.g. 50.000 *-or-* in terms of file-size e.g. 10MB (uncompressed)) or in case you have multiple hostnames in the URIs which requires you to have multiple files - one per hostname.

BTW, the following answer is related on Stackoverflow, but you need to ignore the accepted answer as it is not well researched (like the question itself):

- [Multiple SiteMap: entries in robots.txt?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2594179/367456)

Comment: I can't seem to see where they mention about naming of sitemaps in the provided link.

Comment: The naming of a sitemap is its *location*. Look for *location*.